# Put something around a block of text using regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net

I need some help with regular expressions please. (In .Net 4 and C#)

I need to highlighting a block of text. The text is formated html so I am trying to use a regular expression to find the block when I just know the words in it. Then I want to put span tags around it:

For example if I have :

```
Now x is y the time z for all <bold>quick</bold> brown x foxes to jump over the lazy dogs back"
```

And I want to highlight **"all quick brown foxes"**

I want my result string to be:

```
Now x is y the time z for all <span class="MyHighLight"><bold>quick</bold> brown x foxes</span> to jump over the lazy dogs back"
```

The tricky part is I need to keep the original text, just put spans tags around it.

I thought I would start with replacing the spaces in the string I want to find with ?* to convert it to a regular expression.
**all?*quick?*brown?*foxes**

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose/status of the 'x' in 'brown x foxes' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static string Yellow(this string body, string match)
{
    string result = body;
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(body, match.Replace(" ", "(\\s*|(<[^>]+>)*)+")))                
        result = result.Replace(m.Value, 
            string.Concat("<span class=yellow>", m.Value, "</span>"));
    return result;
}

string s = "Now x is y the time z for all <bold>quick</bold> brown foxes to jump over the lazy dogs back";
string m = "all quick brown foxes";
Console.WriteLine(s.Yellow(m));
```

The result in console is:
Now x is y the time z for <span class=yellow>all <bold>quick</bold> brown foxes</span> to jump over the lazy dogs back

Comment: Thanks - I like the working example. I have this basically but sometimes when I called Regex.Mathes or even Regex.Match, it would not return and was therefore locking up the program - not good. The data that I'm searching is too varied.

Comment: It may happen because the are more than one space characters. You may replace the match.Replace(" " with match.Replace("[\x0020\x00a0\x2000-200d]" and use always html decoded input. An example that will fail is for m = "all&nbsp;quick brown foxes". If you html decoded it (m = HttpUtilities.HtmlDecode(m)) its value will be "all\x00a0quick brown fox", so my making the recommended replacement for matching spaces it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted `.*?` instead of `?*`, which is invalid. So:

```
all.*?quick.*?brown.*?foxes
```

However, this has some issues of its own - there can be words in between. You may instead want something like this:

```
all\s*(\<.+?\>)?\s*quick\s*(\<.+?\>)?\s*brown\s*(\<.+?\>)?\s*foxes
```